Inequality with characteristic and moment generating functions
Suppose $\mu$ is a symmetric probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Define its characteristic and moment generating functions:
\begin{align*}
\phi_{\mu}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\cos(xt) d\mu(x)}
\\
M_{\mu}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\cosh(xt) d\mu(x)}
\end{align*}
We furthermore assume that $|M_{\mu}(t)| < \infty$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
Must it be true, that $\limsup_{t \to \infty} |M_{\mu}(t) \phi_{\mu}(t)| \ge 1$? Must there exist a sequence $t_1, t_2, ... \to \infty$ such that $|M_{\mu}(t_k) \phi_{\mu}(t_k)| \ge 1$ for all $t_k$?
I will note that if $\mu$ represents a normal distribution with mean $0$, then $M_{\mu}(t) \phi_{\mu}(t) = 1$ for all $t$. I've also verified the hypotheses for all classical distributions given on this wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function

I've asked this question on the other mathematical stack exchange too, but perhaps it would fit mathoverflow better.

Under these assumptions $F(z)=\int e^{ixz}, d\mu(x)$ is entire and $\phi(t)=F(t)$, $M(t)=F(it)$.

Also, the table you mention is essentially useless (except for the normal distribution) because a counterexample could only come from $d\mu(x)= f(x), dx$, $f$ also entire.

By the way, I find this question quite interesting. The reception at MSE is disgraceful. If it's any consolation, this kind of thing seems to happen quite regularly there.
